# Converting a loop with an assignment into a comprehension

Tags: python

Converting a loop into a comprehension is simple enough:

```
mylist = []
for word in ['Hello', 'world']:
    mylist.append(word.split('l')[0])
```

to

```
mylist = [word.split('l')[0] for word in ['Hello', 'world']]
```

But I'm not sure how to proceed when the loop involves assigning a value to a reference.

```
mylist = []
for word in ['Hello', 'world']:
    split_word = word.split('l')
    mylist.append(split_word[0]+split_word[1])
```

And the comprehension ends up looking like this:

```
mylist = [word.split('l')[0]+word.split('l')[1] for word in ['Hello', 'world']]
```

This calculates `word.split('l')` multiple times whereas the loop only calculates it once and saves a reference. I've tried the following:

```
mylist = [split_word[0]+split_word[1] for word in ['Hello', 'world'] with word.split('l') as split_word]
```

which fails because `with` doesn't work that way, and:

```
mylist = [split_word[0]+split_word[1] for word in ['Hello', 'world'] for split_word = word.split('l')]
```

which doesn't work either. I'm aware of unpacking via `*` and `**` but I'm not sure where that would fit in here. Is it possible to turn these sorts of loops into comprehensions, hopefully in a tidy way?

Comment: Assignment is a *statement*.  List comprehensions are only for *expressions*.

Comment: Is there any way to perform a calculation once and then refer to its result multiple times without recalculation in the same way that `word` (in the example) can be referred to multiple times, within the comprehension's scope?

Comment: In python3 you could do for example `[first + second for word in the_list for (first, second, *rest) in [word.split('l')]]`

Comment: Slightly uglier version in python2 is `[first + second for word in the_list for (first, second) in [word.split('l')[:2]]]`

Comment: Even if there were a clean way to do this in the general case, all you'd really have accomplished is to write your code horizontally instead of vertically.  Not clear what that buys you.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: Not directly, but there are a number of ways to do it indirectly—you can always do it using either argument passing or generator expressions, and sometimes a lot less verbosely/uglily in other ways.

Comment: @DSM: Plus, the existing code gives a clear name to the intermediate value; while there are ways you can wedge that into one big expression, none of them give you the readability benefits of an assignment statement.

Comment: you could just use [ word.replace('l','',1) for word in ['Hello', 'World' ]

Comment: @LeroyScandal - That produces a different result.

Comment: When you split 'hello', since you have 2 'l's you get 3 values returned. 'Hello'.split('l')
['He', '', 'o'], do you still want split_word[0] and split_word[1] or split_word[-1]?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't directly translate that loop to a comprehension. Comprehensions, being expressions, can only contain expressions, and assignments are statements.

However, that doesn't mean there are no options.

First, at the cost of calling `split` twice, you can just do this:

```
mylist = [word.split('l')[0]+word.split('l')[1] for word in ['Hello', 'world']]
```

But you don't want to call `split` twice.

---

The most general way around that is to use a chain of generator expressions (with one list comprehension at the end) to transform things:

```
words = (word.split('l') for word in ['Hello', 'world'])
mylist = [w[0]+w[1] for w in words]
```

If you really want to merge that all into one expression, you can:

```
mylist = [w[0]+w[1] for w in 
          (word.split('l') for word in ['Hello', 'world'])]
```

But unless you actually *need* it to be in an expression, it's probably more readable not to do that.

---

A more specific way in this case is to replace the `w[0]+w[1]` with something equivalent that doesn't need to reference `w` twice:

```
mylist = [''.join(word.split('l')[:2]) for word in ['Hello', 'world']]
```

And you can always generalize this one, too. You can turn *any* expression into a function, which means you can avoid evaluating any part of it by passing it as an argument to that function. If there isn't a function that does what you want, write it:

```
def join_up(split_word):
    return split_word[0]+split_word[1]
mylist = [join_up(word.split('l')) for word in ['Hello', 'world']]
```

If you need to make that all into one expression without repeating any work, it may not be pretty:

```
mylist = [(lambda split_word: split_word[0]+split_word[1])(word.split('l')) 
          for word in ['Hello', 'world']]
```

---

But ultimately, unless I already had a function lying around that did what I needed, I'd use the chain-of-generator-expressions solution.

Or, of course, just keep it in an explicit loop; there's nothing wrong with `for` loops, and if the intermediate temporary variable makes your code clearer, there's no better way to do that than with an assignment statement.

Comment: good, I think using the generator expression is the most pythonic way around this common issue.

Comment: @wim: Yeah, that's why I put it first. And I wanted to build to the argument-passing solution last, because conceptually it seems like it _should_ be as nice (and it is in, say, Haskell), but it's pretty horrible in practice unless you already have an out-of-line function lying around that does what you need.

Comment: I used to chain comprehensions (e.g. `[c for c in [b for b in a]]`) until I found out that I was doing it backwards from the normal way (e.g. `[c for b in a for c in b]`). It's nice to know that they are not the same thing and it was only backwards for certain values of backwards. :) I'll keep this solution in mind for when a single comprehension is unsuitable.

Answer (score 6):

Be creative.

```
mylist = [''.join(word.split('l')[:2]) for word in ['Hello', 'world']]
```

...

```
mylist = [''.join(operator.itemgetter(0, 1)(word.split('l')))
            for word in ['Hello', 'world']]
```

Comment: I haven't worked with `itemgetter` before - it seems like the ideal tool to use for situations that require something more precise than a slice.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 It also works with dict keys, which slices don't. But mostly you only use itemgetter when they need a function (to pass to map or takewhile, so you tend to forget that it can also do "discontiguous slicing".