# How to get a reference of the list inside the list comprehension in Python

Tags: python, list

In previous Python versions, it was possible to get a reference of the list inside the list comprehension by calling locals()['_[1]']. As it seems not to work anymore, is there another way to get it?

For example, in the following code, I would like to use the result of the mul function as argument of the add function (i.e. I would like to get the last value added to the dict).

```py
mul = lambda a,b: a*b
add = lambda a,b: a+b
res = {f:f(*args) for f, args in [(mul,[4,5]), (add,[2,9])]}
```

**EDIT:**
Please focus on the question, not the example which is only one among others...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting a loop with an assignment into a comprehension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29980865/converting-a-loop-with-an-assignment-into-a-comprehension)

Comment: By the way, `*(arg for arg in args)` is equivalent to `*args`.

Comment: Wouldn't a traditional loop be both easier to write and read? Why the requirement to sqeeze all of this into a list comprehension?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I don't understand how [this topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29980865/converting-a-loop-with-an-assignment-into-a-comprehension) would answer my question ? About the fact that `*(arg for arg in args)` is equivalent to `*args` yes, my mistake. I edited it in order not to distract attention from my question.

Comment: @BryanOakley I have my reasons, here it is just an example. I often need to build lists recursively that's why such a feature would be helpful...

Comment: I linked it as a duplicate because the easiest way to refer to a `list` is to create it first. Create a comprehension/generator, then loop over it in another comprehension/generator, as outlined in that question's accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want, but in a dictionary comprehension?

```
In [79]: result=[]    
In [80]: for f, args in [(add,[4,5]), (mul,[2])]:
    if len(args)==1:
        args.append(result[-1][-1])
    result.append([f,f(*args)])

In [81]: result
Out[81]: [[<function __main__.<lambda>>, 9], 
         [<function __main__.<lambda>>, 18]]
```

If the input list is:

```
[(mul,[4,5]), (add,[2])]
```

the result would be:

```
[[<function __main__.<lambda>>, 20], [<function __main__.<lambda>>, 22]
```

I used a list instead of a dictionary because it is easier to specify 'use the result of the last calculation'.  And I switched the functions in the first case because `add(4,5)` produces `9`, one of the arguments to the 2nd.

In any case, you want to somehow access `result`, and use a value from it in current calculation.  `reduce` has that kind of behavior, keeping a current `state` that serves as one of the inputs to function.  And `numpy` has a `cumsum` (and `cumprod`) that also collects those intermediate values.

How would you have written this list comprehension in an earlier Python (pre 2.7?) where `res` was available in the `locals()` namespace?  That would be been before dictionary comprehensions, right?

---

How about saving the intermediate result in your own variable?

```
In [95]: def g(f,arg):
    x = f(tempval[0],arg)
    tempval[0]=x
    return x
In [96]: tempval=[5]
In [97]: [g(f,arg) for f,arg in [(add,4),(mul,2)]]
Out[97]: [9, 18]
```

Comment: Following [this tutorial](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/204297-the-secret-name-of-list-comprehensions/), I guess I would have written something like this: `[f(*args) for f, args in [(mul,[4,5]), (add,[2,locals()['_[1]'][-1]])]]` But I think it's just not possible anymore. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how to get a reference inside a list in a list comprehension.

But you mentioned wanting to use a comprehension to use the results of your mul function as as part of your add function.  Here is a list comprehension that does that.  (add, [values]) + (mul[values])

python3.4

```
mul = lambda a,b: a*b
add = lambda a,b: a+b
res = {f:f(*args) for f, args in [(mul,[4,5]), (add,[2,9])]}
a = [(mul,[4,5]), (mul,[2,9]), (mul, [14,29])]
b = [(add,[2, 0]), (add,[10, 20]), (add,[20, 15])]
c = list(zip(a, b))
```

In an easier to read for loop:

```
for i in c:
    a = i[0][0](*i[0][1]) # a = mul(*args)
    b = i[1][0](i[1][0](*i[1][1]), a) # b = add(add(*args), mul(*args))
    print(b)
```

> 22
>   48
>   441

As a list comprehension:

```
a_list = [i[1][0](i[1][0](*i[1][1]), i[0][0](*i[0][1]))for i in c]

print(a_list)
```

> [22, 48, 441]